# flexslider not showing the first image loaded from wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, flexslider

I have a flex slider which will load the images from the wordpress site via xmlrpc and play. By inspecting the elements, I saw all the images loaded correctly, but just the first image is not showing. I found out that the ul will have translate3d(-1320px, 0px, 0px) if i am at the first image.

Here is the example of result:

```
<ul id="div_slides" class="slides" style="width: 3200%; -webkit-transition-duration: 0s; transition-duration: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1320px, 0px, 0px);">
<li class="clone" style="width: 1320px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img src="http://www.cugatcasas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_7805-300x200.jpg">
</li>
<li class="" style="width: 1320px; float: left; display: block;">
<img src=""></li>
<li style="width: 1320px; float: left; display: block;" class="flex-active-slide">
<img src="http://www.cugatcasas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_0638-300x225.jpg">
</li>
<li style="width: 1320px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img src="http://www.cugatcasas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_0639-300x225.jpg"></li>
```

the image IMG_7805-300x200.jpg (first one) is not showing.
Is it because of wordpress response or because of slider(translate3d)?
How to avoid this?